# jquery repeater taking last data record when added

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery.repeater

using for each loop I have to retrieve data however when adding new record data-repeater-create is taking default value as the last record of data even the element id is different.

````
                                     <div data-repeater-list="car">
                                      <?php foreach ($user_portfolio as $p_details) {
  $p_title = $p_details['portfolio_title'];
  $p_desc=$p_details['portfolio_desc'];
  $p_expert = $p_details['portfolio_expert_id'];
  $p_id = $p_details['portfolio_id'];
?>
                                                <div data-repeater-item>
                                                    <div class="form row">
                                                        <div class="form-group mb-1 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                                            <label for="email-addr">Title</label>
                                                            <br>
                      <input type="text" name="port_id" value="<?php if(!empty($p_id)) {echo $p_id; } else { echo "";}?>">
 <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="portfolio_title<?php echo $p_id;?>" placeholder="Title " name="portfolio_title" value="<?php if(!empty($p_title)) {echo $p_title;} else {echo ""; }?>">
                                                        </div>```


below using data-repeater-create i am adding empty field however its taking last record as default value and I able to see in view source


                                             ``` <?php } //end of foreach?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group overflow-hidden">
                                                <div class="col-12">
                                                    <button data-repeater-create class="btn btn-theme" type="button">
                                                        <i class="ft-plus"></i> Add
                                                    </button>
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme">
                                                    <i class="la la-check-square-o"></i> Save
                                                </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                          </form>```
````